# Check if any subscriber throws an exception in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I'm trying to make a reactive RabbitMQ listener that allows us to process each message with multiple subscribers. We only want to `ack` the message when all subscribers finish successfully.

This is my current setup:

```
Observable
    .fromCallable(() -> {
        // Set up connection
        return consumer;
    })
    .flatMap(consumer -> Observable
        .fromCallable(consumer::nextDelivery)
        .doOnError(throwable -> {
            try {
                consumer.getChannel().getConnection().close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) { }
        })
        .repeat())
    .retryWhen(observable -> observable.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .publish()
    .refCount();
```

This will set up the connection once, share all messages with all subscribers, and reconnect after 3 seconds if this fails anywhere due to e.g. Rabbit becoming unavailable.

What I still need to do is `ack` or `nack` the message. Since all our message handlers are idempotent, I can just requeue the message if any handler happens to fail, to ensure every handler finishes successfully.

Is there any way to tell if *any* subscriber failed? I was currently thinking about subscribing something like this:

```
public void subscribe(Action1 action) {
    deliveries
        .flatMap(delivery -> Observable
            .just(delivery)
            .doOnNext(action)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                // nack
            })
            .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                // ack
            })
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

But this obviously `ack`s or `nack`s on the first failure or success. Is there any way to `merge` all subscribers of a particular message and then check for errors or completion?

I also tried something like using an `AtomicInteger` to count all subscribers and then count the successes / failures but obviously whenever someone subscribes or unsubscribes during processing there's no trivial way of syncing that without blocking the entire processing step.

I could also give every subscriber an `Observable<Delivery>` and make them return that with an error or a completion, similar to `retryWhen` (as sort of a reply channel), but I have no way of generating the required number of observables upfront and merging them afterwards.

Any ideas? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **onErrorResumeNext** to control the exception propagated from your pipeline and set the **nack**, and then use your onComplete as ***ack***

Here an example

```
Observable.just(null).map(Object::toString)
                     .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
                     .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                     .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) : Observable.just(null).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                                                     Schedulers.newThread())
                     .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                                              System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                                              return Observable.just("I save the world!");
                                          })
                     .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this take into account potential errors from multiple subscribers though?

Comment: I don't really see how I could apply this. I put the `onErrorResumeNext` before or after the `refCount`? And how do I know all subscribers processed the message successfully in order to `ack` it? I don't want subscribers to close, because there will be subsequent messages coming in from rabbit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`Observable.mergeDelayError`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html), and then one of the `.onError*` methods.

The first one will propagate the error only after all observables have completed/errored out; the second will allow you to handle the error *after* processing has finished.

Edit: To get the counts, count the successes:

```
Object message = ...;
List<Action1<?>> actions = ...;
Observable.from(actions)
 .map(action ->
    Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(action.call(message))
    .ignoreEmements()
    .cast(Integer.class)
    .switchIfEmpty(1)
    .onErrorReturnResumeNext(e->Observable.empty())
 )
 .compose(Observable::merge)
 .count();
```

It's a bit convoluted and it could be made clearer: make the calls, ignore errors from them, count successes.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the right thing. I'm still struggling to find a way to produce the correct number of observables. How do I know how many subscribers will receive the message? Only `refCount` has an accurate subscriber number AFAIK, and that's blocking on each message to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If someone subscribes while processing the stream, it won't get the message, but the count will include it and be out of sync? I don't have a list of subscribers, I let `RxJava` handle that, but looking at your example I might have to keep track of subscribers myself and explicitly dispatch to them to make this work.